# Foundation for Apps inside of Lumen

Tags: laravel, zurb-foundation, lumen

I am attempting to install Foundation for Apps inside of Lumen (a php framework).

I am having a hard time figuring out how to configure front-router inside my gulpfile to create the correct route.js file.

1. the file exposed on localhost is at /public/index.php (loads fine)
2. It loads app.css, foundation.js, templates.js, routes.js and app.js just fine, which are all at public/build/assets (I changed the gulpfile accordingly).
3. However, the routes.js file shows:

   [{"name":"home","url":"/","path":"client/templates/home.html"}];

instead of:

```
[{"name":"home","url":"/","path":"build/templates/home.html"}];
```

How do I fix this?

My gulpfile is:

```
// FOUNDATION FOR APPS TEMPLATE GULPFILE
// -------------------------------------
// This file processes all of the assets in the "client" folder, combines them with the Foundation for Apps assets, and outputs the finished files in the "build" folder as a finished app.

// 1. LIBRARIES
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var $        = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var argv     = require('yargs').argv;
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var rimraf   = require('rimraf');
var router   = require('front-router');
var sequence = require('run-sequence');

// Check for --production flag
var isProduction = !!(argv.production);

// 2. FILE PATHS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var paths = {
  assets: [
    './client/**/*.*',
    '!./client/templates/**/*.*',
    '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'
  ],
  // Sass will check these folders for files when you use @import.
  sass: [
    'client/assets/scss',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/scss'
  ],
  // These files include Foundation for Apps and its dependencies
  foundationJS: [
    'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
    'bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill.js',
    'bower_components/tether/tether.js',
    'bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/vendor/**/*.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/**/*.js',
    '!bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/app.js'
  ],
  // These files are for your app's JavaScript
  appJS: [
    'client/assets/js/app.js'
  ]
};

// 3. TASKS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Cleans the build directory
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf('../public/build', cb);
});

// Copies everything in the client folder except templates, Sass, and JS
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.assets, {
    base: './client/'
  })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build'))
  ;
});

// Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
gulp.task('copy:templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(router({
      path: '../public/build/assets/js/routes.js',
      root: './client/templates'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/templates'))
  ;
});

// Compiles the Foundation for Apps directive partials into a single JavaScript file
gulp.task('copy:foundation', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/**/*.html')
    .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
      prefix: 'components/',
      moduleName: 'foundation',
      declareModule: false
    }))
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe($.concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js'))
  ;

  // Iconic SVG icons
  gulp.src('./bower_components/foundation-apps/iconic/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/img/iconic/'))
  ;

  cb();
});

// Compiles Sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('client/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: paths.sass,
      outputStyle: (isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'nested'),
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/css/'))
  ;
});

// Compiles and copies the Foundation for Apps JavaScript, as well as your app's custom JS
gulp.task('uglify', ['uglify:foundation', 'uglify:app']);

gulp.task('uglify:foundation', function(cb) {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.foundationJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('foundation.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('uglify:app', function() {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

// RR: took this out; going to use php artisan serve
// Starts a test server, which you can view at http://localhost:8080
// gulp.task('server', ['build'], function() {
//   gulp.src('./build')
//     .pipe($.webserver({
//       port: 8080,
//       host: 'localhost',
//       fallback: 'index.html',
//       livereload: true,
//       open: true
//     }))
//   ;
// });

// Builds your entire app once, without starting a server
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  sequence('clean', ['copy', 'copy:foundation', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy:templates', cb);
});

// RR: changed to not run server
// Default task: builds your app, starts a server, and recompiles assets when they change
// gulp.task('default', ['server'], function () {
gulp.task('default', ['build'], function () {
  // Watch Sass
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/scss/**/*', './scss/**/*'], ['sass']);

  // Watch JavaScript
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/js/**/*', './js/**/*'], ['uglify:app']);

  // Watch static files
  gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.*', '!./client/templates/**/*.*', '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'], ['copy']);

  // Watch app templates
  gulp.watch(['./client/templates/**/*.html'], ['copy:templates']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

1. install gulp-replace

   ```
   npm install --save-dev gulp-replace
   ```
2. create a var for it:

   ```
   var replace  = require('gulp-replace');
   ```
3. create a task.

   ```
   // RR: Changes paths in routes.js to build/templates/
   gulp.task('update-route', function(){
     gulp.src(['../public/build/assets/js/routes.js'])
       .pipe(replace('templates', 'build/templates'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'));
   });
   ```
4. add to build task

   ```
   gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
     sequence('clean', ['copy', 'copy:foundation', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy:templates', 'update-route', cb);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working gulpfile, in case anyone else needs it.  I'm sure there are better ways of getting it all done, but hey, -- it works!

gulpfile is located at project-name/ffa/

php artisan serve is running a server on port 8000 and responds to livereload.

working front-end directory is at project-name/ffa/client/

build goes into project-name/public/build/

```
    // FOUNDATION FOR APPS TEMPLATE GULPFILE
    // -------------------------------------
    // This file processes all of the assets in the "client" folder, combines them with the Foundation for Apps assets, and outputs the finished files in the "build" folder as a finished app.

    // 1. LIBRARIES
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    var $        = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
    var argv     = require('yargs').argv;
    var gulp     = require('gulp');
    var rimraf   = require('rimraf');
    var router   = require('front-router');
    var sequence = require('run-sequence');
    var replace  = require('gulp-replace');
    var livereload  = require('gulp-livereload');

    // Check for --production flag
    var isProduction = !!(argv.production);

    // 2. FILE PATHS
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    var paths = {
      assets: [
        './client/**/*.*',
        '!./client/templates/**/*.*',
        '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'
      ],
      // Sass will check these folders for files when you use @import.
      sass: [
        'client/assets/scss',
        'bower_components/foundation-apps/scss'
      ],
      // These files include Foundation for Apps and its dependencies
      foundationJS: [
        'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
        'bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill.js',
        'bower_components/tether/tether.js',
        'bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js',
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/vendor/**/*.js',
        'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/**/*.js',
        '!bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/app.js'
      ],
      // These files are for your app's JavaScript
      appJS: [
        'client/assets/js/app.js'
      ]
    };

    // 3. TASKS
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    // Cleans the build directory
    gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
      rimraf('../public/build', cb);
    });

    // Copies everything in the client folder except templates, Sass, and JS
    gulp.task('copy', function() {
      return gulp.src(paths.assets, {
        base: './client/'
      })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build'))
      ;
    });

    // Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
    gulp.task('copy:templates', function() {
      return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(router({
          path: '../public/build/assets/js/routes.js',
          root: 'client'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/templates'))
      ;
    });

    // RR: Changes paths in routes.js to build/templates/
    gulp.task('update-route', function(){
      gulp.src(['../public/build/assets/js/routes.js'])
        .pipe(replace('templates', 'build/templates'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'));
    });


    // Compiles the Foundation for Apps directive partials into a single JavaScript file
    gulp.task('copy:foundation', function(cb) {
      gulp.src('bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/**/*.html')
        .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
          prefix: 'components/',
          moduleName: 'foundation',
          declareModule: false
        }))
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe($.concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js'))
      ;

      // Iconic SVG icons
      gulp.src('./bower_components/foundation-apps/iconic/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/img/iconic/'))
      ;

      cb();
    });

    // Compiles Sass
    gulp.task('sass', function () {
      return gulp.src('client/assets/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe($.sass({
          includePaths: paths.sass,
          outputStyle: (isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'nested'),
          errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/css/'))
      ;
    });

    // Compiles and copies the Foundation for Apps JavaScript, as well as your app's custom JS
    gulp.task('uglify', ['uglify:foundation', 'uglify:app']);

    gulp.task('uglify:foundation', function(cb) {
      var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
        .on('error', function (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }));

      return gulp.src(paths.foundationJS)
        .pipe(uglify)
        .pipe($.concat('foundation.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'))
      ;
    });

    gulp.task('uglify:app', function() {
      var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
        .on('error', function (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }));

      return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
        .pipe(uglify)
        .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/build/assets/js/'))
      ;
    });


    // Builds your entire app once, without starting a server
    gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
      sequence('clean', ['copy', 'copy:foundation', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy:templates', 'update-route', cb);
    });

    // Default task: builds your app, and recompiles assets when they change
    gulp.task('default', ['build'], function () {

      livereload.listen(35729);

      // Watch Sass
      gulp.watch(['./client/assets/scss/**/*', './scss/**/*'], ['build']);

      // Watch JavaScript
      gulp.watch(['./client/assets/js/**/*', './js/**/*'], ['build']);

      // Watch static files
      gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.*', '!./client/templates/**/*.*', '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'], ['build']);

      // Watch app templates
      gulp.watch(['./client/templates/**/*.html'], ['build']);

      gulp.on('stop', function(){
        livereload.changed("");
      });

    });
```